# Changing the position of the video

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I want the video to be in top left side of the gui but i dont know how to do it

[image]

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1481x929")
window.configure(bg = "#ffffff")

canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#ffffff",
    height = 929,
    width = 1481,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")


canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

window.title("Video player")

lblVideo = Label(window)
lblVideo.pack()

player = tkvideo("prediction.mp4", lblVideo, loop=1, size=(700,500))
player.play()

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: canvas.pack(side=LEFT, sticky='w')

Answer (score 0):

As @toyotasupra said, your can use `canvas.pack(side=LEFT, sticky='w'`.

But I would recommend using the tkinter grid layout manager, which you can view [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter). Then you can use the code `component.grid(column=0, row=0)` to place your video on your Tkinter GUI.